# Error V6059 upon checkout within store

Tags: expresso-store, error

Whats this error supposed to mean? V6059

```
                    {if error:payment_method}
                        <div class='error-panel'>Error: {error:payment_method}</div>
                    {/if}
```

Comment: It depends which payment gateway you are using, and what your template code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like you're using eWay Rapid as your payment gateway. Error code V6059 is a "Redirect URL Invalid" response.

Ensure that you're using the correct tags in your template. In particular you need to ensure you're using the `{exp:store:payment}` tag and not `{exp:store:checkout}`. This is to deal with their rather different *transparent redirect* gateway.

Also ensure that you have the other input fields named accordingly. More information on this [in the docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/payment_gateways.html#eway_rapid_3_0).

Finally, if you're still having problems with the redirect getting back to your site it could be an issue with [Secure Forms](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/spam_protection.html#secure-mode). You can try turning these off to test but it should be resolved in the latest version of Store (v2.2.0). If you're upgrading then be sure that you're running EE 2.7+ as that is now a minimum requirement.